# VPN causes problems connection to local SQL database and other resources

Tags: vpn

We've got a MS Small Business Server hosting our Exchange and SQL. Our timesheet system makes use of SQL server, but when we connect to client sites using any form of VPN we can no longer connect to the local SQL server.

I'm no network/server specialist so I'm hoping someone can point me in the right direction.

Regards,
Jacques

Comment: Can you connect to any local resources after making the VPN connection?

Comment: I can connect to the actual server. Exchange for example is still accessible it seems. And file share still works on that server, it's primarily SQL that we can't connect to with our timesheet application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your SQL server is not accessible from your VPN subnet.  This could be for any number of reasons, including that it's designed this way for security purposes.

Comment: So what could I possible check to see how this is setup?

Comment: @Jacques You mention you can connect to the actual server, but not SQL, which means it's probably a firewall rule.

Comment: I don't know how to explain this, but today I'm not getting the issue at all. This is the first time that I don't have the issue. I've been able to work on the VPN all day and our timesheet application had no problem accessing our SQL server. I'm a bit lost for an explanation because we didn't change anything

Comment: @Jacques  The only thing I can think of (other than "huh, weird") is that there could be an IP address conflict on your network if your VPN is not setup to use a different subnet or address pool.  It's possible this is created when you connect to a client network, but that wouldn't explain why you could access one protocol and not the other over VPN the other day, and access both today.  I'd give your network guy a hard time about it. :)

Comment: We're still having issues. I've been reading more and more and many people mention split tunneling and so on, but these things are above my pay grade! Have no idea how to solve it. We're having the same issues now with our home users logging into our work VPN